# Input Box in an MFC CWinApp program?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

I need an input box in a UI program that is already written derived from the CWinnApp class and using MFC.

I see it is using message boxes but I don't see any examples of input boxes....

How do I do this?

(Using Visual Studio 6.0 in C++)

Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know it's something that's often required, but there isn't a built-in input box in MFC, so you'll have to create your own. I usually just create a simple dialog with a label and edit box (the dialog already comes with OK/Cancel buttons), then create a class, say `CInputDlg`, add member variables for the label and edit box, and just call it like any other dialog:

```
CInputDlg dialog;
dialog.m_label = TEXT("Enter a number:");
if (dialog.DoModal() == IDOK) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Do i need to inherit from a specific class to use DoModal? The CDialog? is there any example of such a class?

Comment: The ClassWizard should do everything for you, including creating the class and adding the required control variables. [Here's an article](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=61) that guides you through this process.

Comment: ClassWizard should generate the header automatically, so I don't know why you're getting an error. Make sure that `IDD_CUSTOM_DIALOG` is actually the name of your dialog resource and also that `Resource.h` is included in the class header.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a dialog box and place an edit control on it. There is no automagic solution. You have to code it or find some code on the web.

Answer (score 1):

When you created your MFC App, which type of project did you tell the wizard to generate?  Usually I do mine as a Dialog app, and then it's a simple matter of placing a text box on the dialog.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for a pop-up (modal) input box, similar to a message box.

Comment: @casablanca, my mind-reading skills must be a little off today. I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2008 it is straightforward:

1. In the resource view, right click on Dialog Directory and choose
   add resource... or insert dialog(choose this option id you are not
   sure what kind of dialog).
2. Click on tools and add  a static text and Edit Control and
   whatever tools you want to add type in the name of the dialog, and
   the name of the class, this will add a header file and .cpp file to
   your project directly.
3. Add the controls that you want to add to your class