# How can I create a pre-render input window in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have modified [Nehe's terrain tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/beautiful_landscapes_by_means_of_height_mapping/16006/) so that it generates a terrain using Perlin noise instead of loading the static .raw file that comes with the tutorial. I want to specify the parameters for perlin noise (frequency, amplitude, number of octaves) before rendering the terrain. In fact, **I just want to create a window that takes those 3 parameters and then dies**, I don't need anything else, I do my interfaces on GLUT, I just want this particular app to run this way.

How can I do that? What should be modified in the [Nehe project](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/vc/lesson34.zip)? I understand [MFC doesn't have a built-in input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507085/input-box-in-an-mfc-cwinapp-prgram)?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want a window taking the parameters, instead of via command line? If you can pass them in there, it'll definitely be cleaner (but may not work for your purposes).

Comment: I prefer not showing the command line for this particular demo.

Comment: why do you need a window for passing this parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiary with the tutorial but if you want the input box to not be seen but to precess parameters could you just create the window as invisible?