# MFC Single Document Application User Input

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, window

My problem is quite simple but i haven't yet found a way around it. I'm currently making a **Single Document MFC Application** and i need user's input in any way possible. I have explored **CDialog** but haven't figured out how to make it work. I need very basic integer input from user in the window. This is my first time developing using **MFC** and i have tried everywhere but haven't found the solution. If anyone can help i'd really appreciate it.
**Edit:**
I am using CPaintDC to draw different shapes like ellipse and square in my application:

```
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    dc.Ellipse(200, 200, 400, 400);
```

All i need to do is to get user's input for the points of ellipse and use the function above to draw the shapes.

```
dc.Ellipse(x1,y1,x2,y2);
// where x1,y1 and x2,y2 are user inputs. any way to get the user input will do.. thanks
```

Following are the links i have already explored:

[Interactive Service - Display Dialog Box & Get Input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428155/interactive-service-display-dialog-box-get-input-from-user)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13330/Using-Dialog-Templates-to-create-an-InputBox-in-C

nothing changing. this is my code :::

```
 void AddCircle::OnBnClickedOk()
 {

    CDialogEx::OnOK();

    CString abc;   
    x1ctrl.GetWindowText(abc);
    int x1;
    _stscanf(abc, _T("%d"), &x1); //convert CString to integer value

    y1ctrl.GetWindowText(abc);
    int y1;
    _stscanf(abc, _T("%d"), &y1); //convert CString to integer value

    x2ctrl.GetWindowText(abc);
    int x2;
    _stscanf(abc, _T("%d"), &x2); 
    y2ctrl.GetWindowText(abc);
    int y2;
    _stscanf(abc, _T("%d"), &y2); 
    Invalidate();
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.Ellipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507085/input-box-in-an-mfc-cwinapp-prgram

Comment: The link in your comment seems to cover your requirement quite well -- what have you tried and what **exactly** is your problem? [please edit your question with the details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one `EditControl` from toolbox. Right Click on Edit Control->Add variable, give variable name say `m_myedit`.

On button click write this code

```
CString abc;   //Take CString variable 
m_myedit.GetWindowText(abc);   //read value from textbox
int x1;  
_stscanf(abc, _T("%d"), &x1); //convert CString to integer value
```

Use different `editbox` to get value of x2,y1 and y2.